# Create an NCX file with Notepad++ and Regular expression

Tags: html, regex, xml, notepad++

I have a HTML Table of Contents page containing list of book chapters with hyperlinks:

```
<a href="final/main.html">Multimedia Implementation</a><br/>
<a href="final/toc.html">Table of Contents</a><br/>
<a href="final/pref01.html">About the Author</a><br/>
<a href="final/pref02.html">About the Technical Reviewers</a><br/>
<a href="final/pref03.html">Acknowledgments</a><br/>
<a href="final/part01.html">Part I: Introduction and Overview</a><br/>
<a href="final/ch01.html">Chapter 1. Technical Overview</a><br/>
...
```

I want create NCX file for a Kindle book which must contain details as follows:

```
<navPoint id="n1" playOrder="1">
<navLabel>
<text>Multimedia Implementation</text>
</navLabel>
<content src="final/main.html"/>
</navPoint>
<navPoint id="n2" playOrder="2">
<navLabel>
<text>Table of Contents</text>
</navLabel>
<content src="final/toc.html"/>
</navPoint>
<navPoint id="n3" playOrder="3">
<navLabel>
<text>About the Author</text>
</navLabel>
<content src="final/pref01.html"/>
</navPoint>
...
```

I'm using Notepad++: is it possible automate this process with regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do everything using regex.. you can split the problem into two parts..

- generate strings like `<navPoint id="n1" playOrder="1">` using program logic (increment variable)
- remaining you can do with regex

Use the following regex to match:

```
<a\shref="([^"]*)">([^<]*)<\/a><br\/>
```

And replace with:

```
(generated string)<navLabel>\n<text>\2</text>\n<content src="\1"/>\n</navPoint>
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fY0fR6/4)

Comment: What can be way to generate incremental numbering of the `<navPoint id="n" playOrder="">`? There are missing slash in navPoint closing tag.

Comment: create a variable `(var x =1)` build the string to be generated (`'<navPoint id="n' + x + '" playOrder="' + x + '">'`  then append with replace string and replace.. now increment `var x` (x=x+1).. repeat for all matches..

Comment: what do you mean by macro?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possibly to replace the links with `<navpoint>` tags. The only thing I found no solution for is the incremental numbering of the `<navpoint>` attributes `id` and `playOrder`...

The following regex will do most of the work:

```
/^<a[^>]*href="([^"]+)"[^>]*([^<]+).*$/gm
```

substitute with:

```
<navpoint id="n" playOrder="">\n<navLabel><text>$2</text></navLabel>\n<content src="$1" />\n</navpoint>\n
```

Regex details

```
/^<a     .. only parse lines that start with an `<a` tag
.*href=" .. find the first occurance of `href="`
([^"]+)  .. capture the text and stop when a " is found
"[^>]*>  .. find the end of the <a> tag
([^<]+)  .. capture the text and stop when a < is found (i.e. the </a> tag)
.*$/     .. continue to end of the line
gm       .. search the whole string and parse each line individually
```

More detailled (but also more confusing) explanation is here:
https://regex101.com/r/gA0yJ2/1
This link also demonstrates how the regex is working. You can test changes there if you like